# BeanCreationException on Spring TestNG PowerMock test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testng, powermock, spring-test

I'm getting `BeanCreationException` when using `@AutoWired` (Spring Annotation) and `@PrepareForTest` (PowerMock) and running my Spring enabled TestNG test.

I have a Spring controller, picked up via component scan.

I'm testing with TestNG, Mockito, and PowerMock.

I'm trying to spy on an auto wired controller thats autowired into the test, via: `@AutoWired` annotation.

Here's the beginning of the test class:

```
@PowerMockIgnore("*")
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-test.xml" })
@PrepareForTest(IWantAHamburgerController.class)
public class IWantAHamburgerControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    @Autowired 
    private MockHttpSession session;
    @Autowired 
    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    @Autowired
    private IWantAHamburgerController iWantAHamburgerController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

     @BeforeClass
     public void setup() {
         this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();

         // see the note at the bottom of this post about this line
         //iWantAHamburgerController = (IWantAHamburgerController) applicationContext.getBean("iWantAHamburgerController");
     }
```

I'm trying to test a GET method on `IWantAHamburgerController`. This is what the test looks like:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetHamburgerAfterAskingThisQuestion() throws Exception {
        Principal p = PowerMockito.mock(Principal.class);
        PowerMockito.when(p.getName()).thenReturn("oneofthefiveguys");

        IWantAHamburgerController spy = PowerMockito.spy(iWantAHamburgerController);

        PowerMockito.doReturn("oneofthefiveguys").when(spy).getUserName("oneofthefiveguys");

        mockMvc.perform(get("/hamburgers/everythinghamburger.html")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("jsp/hamburger/everythinghamburger"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("jsp/hamburger/everythinghamburger"));

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(spy).invoke("initGrill", "oneofthefiveguys");

        new org.mockito.internal.debugging.MockitoDebuggerImpl().printInvocations(spy);
    }
```

Inside the test I want to spy on the autowired `iWantAHamburgerController` in order to verify that `initGrill` was called by the GET method on the controller.

If I remove `@PrepareForTest(IWantAHamburgerController.class)` I do not get a `BeanCreationException`, but then PowerMock doesn't work.

Note: I've tried to manually set the `iWantAHamburgerController` bean, but when I do, I get a `ClassCastException`.

Here's the full stack:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'com.fiveguys.controllers.IWantAHamburgerControllerTest': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.fiveguys.controllers.IWantAHamburgerController
>   com.fiveguys.controllers.IWantAHamburgerControllerTest.iWantAHamburgerController;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.fiveguys.controllers.IWantAHamburgerController] found for
>   dependency: expected

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this problem? I'm running into all sorts of non-deterministic conflicts between Spring, TestNG, and Powermock

Comment: Thomas Kessler, @Ross117 were you able to get a solution for this. I have come across similar issue. The powermock-module-javaagent seems to cause an issue.